# Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element. WebPack Config Caching

Tags: javascript, webpack

I got this error after `yarn run build`

```
Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
    at invariant (main.d42bd1bcd415c653488b.js:31237)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (vendors.7a43e73f48618444f591.js:17244)
    at Object.render (vendors.7a43e73f48618444f591.js:17323)
    at Module.QfWi (main.d42bd1bcd415c653488b.js:38479)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.01308d7cc7f8f5e719e6.js:79)
    at Object.0 (main.d42bd1bcd415c653488b.js:1113)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.01308d7cc7f8f5e719e6.js:79)
    at checkDeferredModules (runtime.01308d7cc7f8f5e719e6.js:46)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (runtime.01308d7cc7f8f5e719e6.js:33)
    at main.d42bd1bcd415c653488b.js:1
```

I implement caching webpack config.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/src',
  entry: ['regenerator-runtime/runtime', './index'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'ZBGCard-tool',
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: []
  }
}
```

When I am not using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and output file name `bundle.js', it was working fine, but after I integrate caching webpack config, it doesn't work.
I got error above.

This is the link I followed to integrate caching webpack config.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

Comment: see if solution on this thread helps https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/2615

Comment: @ashishsingh It doesn't work my side. please check my webpack.config.js